# If statements for browser support

Tags: html, if-statement, browser-support

Are If statements available for html because I want this text to pop up when someone is using internet explorer `<p>You are using Internet Explorer we don't support this browser</p>`

And for firefox `</p>Your browser is supported</p>`

Is this possible?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My title</title>
<p class="accent">
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is <comment>not</comment> IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
</p>
</head>
<body>
MY code here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can do it with CSS and HTML, with CSS detect the browser and DISPLAY or HIDE a HTML TAG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no HTML if statement, but Internet Explorer has something called [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). So you could say

```html
<!--[if IE]>
<p>You are using Internet Explorer we don't support this browser</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
</p>Your browser is supported</p>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Although, the second part covers everything else, not only Firefox browser.

Comment: So does the ! mean not IE

Comment: @user2748588 Yes, it does. See the link, where you can see how to use this to detect various IE versions.

Comment: I don't get it I just used IE and had the code from http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html and it said this browser is not ie

Comment: @user2748588 What does the framed text below the heading **Test** say?

Comment: @user2748588 Sorry, I missed your code yesterday. I just copied the code into wordpad and saved it as a text file. I loaded it into IE8 and the output says it's IE8 or higher, lower than 9 and higher than 6. Looks perfect to me. Although, I would put the paragraphs into the body and not in the head.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery.browser: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

> The $.browser property provides
>   information about the web browser that
>   is accessing the page, as reported by
>   the browser itself. It contains flags
>   for each of the four most prevalent
>   browser classes (Internet Explorer,
>   Mozilla, Webkit, and Opera) as well as
>   version information.
>
> Available flags are:
>
> webkit (as of jQuery 1.4) safari
>   (deprecated) opera msie mozilla This
>   property is available immediately. It
>   is therefore safe to use it to
>   determine whether or not to call
>   $(document).ready(). The $.browser
>   property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3,
>   and its functionality may be moved to
>   a team-supported plugin in a future
>   release of jQuery.
>
> Because $.browser uses
>   navigator.userAgent to determine the
>   platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing
>   by the user or misrepresentation by
>   the browser itself. It is always best
>   to avoid browser-specific code
>   entirely where possible. The $.support
>   property is available for detection of
>   support for particular features rather
>   than relying on $.browser.